# Deploying AWX in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ansible-awx

I am trying to deploy the AWX in kubernetes cluster and it seems working from the looking at the surface but when i dig deep into logs of AWX pods then i see the pods are waiting for database migration but unable to do so. I get this log in both awx-task and awx-web pods.

```
$ kubectl logs pod/awx-task-ff5874db-8qqfq
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting for database migrations...
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 1 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 0.5 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 2 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 1 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 3 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 2 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 4 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 4 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 5 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 8 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 6 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 16 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 7 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 8 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 9 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 10 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 11 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 12 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 13 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 14 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
[wait-for-migrations] Attempt 15 of 30
[wait-for-migrations] Waiting 30 seconds before next attempt
```

I tried running migration getting inside the container but it show following error

```
bash-5.1$ awx-manage migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: Name or service not known

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/awx-manage", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(manage())
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/awx/__init__.py", line 184, in manage
    if (connection.pg_version // 10000) < 12:
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 436, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 119, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 705, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/connection.py", line 728, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection is bad: Name or service not known
```

Comment: can you add some information about how you run AWX and the DB it's supposed to be using because `connection is bad: Name or service not known` hints something's off when connecting to the DB but hard to help without knowing more about the setup

Comment: I am using awx 2.5.0 with k8 1.27 and i am deploying it by using command "make deploy" . For awx deployment i simply applied awx-demo.yaml file that is includes in the root of awx-operator project.